# Clustered Indexing or Non- Clustered Indexing for employees database

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, database-schema

I did work on a database of employees where organization consisting of hundreds of employees in different office branches across country. Now HR department decided some new benefits and bonus policies according to pay scale and Designation of employees. So they need to update employees’ relevant record based on specific criteria.  Now database is already complete. But which indexing technique will be better for above scenario for updation of records?

As per my research there are two type indexing techniques could be applied.

1)      Clustered Indexing

2)      Non- Clustered Indexing

But I don’t know what difference between both of them is and what is suitable for this case

Comment: Looks like you are specifically talking about `SQL Server`; then why have you tagged with `MySQL`?

Comment: As a rule almost every table should have a clustered index. You can only have one clustered index per table. Choose a clustered index, then add nonclustered indexes for other attributes you need to index.